# How to get text area value from a javascript element

Tags: javascript

If I have a div element and I add a textarea to the innerHTML like the following:

```
tMessageWindow.innerHTML="<textarea rows = '22' cols='67'> Test text </textarea>"
```

How can I then retrieve the value of the text area?

I've tried tvalue=tMessageWindow.value and that doesn't work of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
var tvalue = tMessageWindow.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`tMessageWindow.childNodes[0].value` should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to the textarea (for example id="foobar") so you can then get the value by using

```
document.getElementById("foobar").value;
```